# Spring Cloud Gateway - RedisRateLimiter - How to point to a different Redis other than localhost?

Tags: spring-cloud-gateway

I am creating a Service Gateway for my project using Spring Cloud Gateway. Currently, I am trying to do rateLimiting for one of my APIs. I tried few samples provided on github which uses RedisRateLimiter. I am getting following exception on every request -

2018-11-01 21:33:39.321 ERROR 15568 --- [     parallel-2] o.s.c.g.f.ratelimit.RedisRateLimiter     : Error determining if user allowed from redis
org.springframework.data.redis.RedisConnectionFailureException: Unable to connect to Redis; nested exception is io.lettuce.core.RedisConnectionException: Unable to connect to localhost:6379

My question is - What is the way to change the redis configurations? I have Redis installed on a different machine. Is there some property wherein I can provide my Redis host and port so that it does not point to localhost?

Answer (score 2):

I connected my API gateway to the Redis instance which was on amazon elastic cache. Below is the configuration I have done in my **bootstrap.yml** of my API gateway microservice.

```
spring:
  redis:
    host: xyz (provide host name here)
    port: 6379 (provide port here)
    jedis:
      pool:
        maxIdle: 50 # max idle connections in the pool
        minIdle: 10 # min idle connections in the pool
        maxActive: -1 # no limit to the number of active connections
        maxWait: 30000 # time limit to get a connection - only applies if maxActive is finite
```

You can use the Jedis client to add further configurations.

Hope it helps.